# Why aren't these two layers floating beside each other?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make two divs display beside each other, and I even floated them to no luck. Why is that?

```
<div class="popup-container">
  <div class="popup-header">
      <div class="popup-image-holder"></div>

    <div class="image-titles">Content for  class "image-titles" Goes Here</div>
  </div>
</div>


.popup-container {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 764px;
}
.popup-header {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 21px;
    height: 243px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* add this to contain floated children */
}
.popup-image-holder {
    float; left;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.image-titles {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #666;
}
```

Thanks
Edit: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyskv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. you mistyped ; instead of : in `popup-image-holder` div try this

```
  .popup-image-holder {
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
height: 165px;
width: 165px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kyskv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the 'display' attribute to the outer most container at the least.

For example:

`.popup-container {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 764px;
}`
Add it to the other elements as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but without results.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the code. Thanks for the help James :)